# Create an change() event on a select box inside a loaded html piece (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, load

I have a webpage which consists of a select box. On change, I load an external piece of html using the jQuery

```
.load()
```

which includes a new select box. I then want to create a new .change() event on this select box, but this does not work (since the new select box is not loaded into the DOM?). I've tried to put the .change() code of the second select box in a function, like this:

```
.load('test.php',function() {
    $('.selectbox2').change()...
});
```

But this still does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

try using [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('#divId')
    .delegate('.selectbox2', 'change', function() { // change code })
    .load('test.php')
```

OR

you can use [`livequery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Answer (score 1):

or try using [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)